# Математические операции с дженериками

Tags: java, generics

попытался создать метод, который в качестве аргументов будет принимать два числа произвольного типа, и выдавать результат в виде числа того же типа что и аргументы.

```
private static <T extends Number> T middler(T arg1, T arg2){
            T res = (arg2+(arg1-arg2)/2);
            return res;
        }
```

при этом, Эклипс указывает на ошибку в `arg1-arg2`. текст ошибки следующий:

```
The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T
```

как указать, что допустимыми типами могут быть числовые типы?

Comment: Я конечно не проф, но мне кажется он так и говорит, что не может выполнить операции не зная тип... А чтоб выполнить это, вам видимо нужно явно указать это...то есть привести к типу оба аргумента....`if( T instanceof Double) {
 привести к типу дабл переменные и сделать над ними операции
  }
  else if( T instanceof Integer) {
 привести к типу интежер переменные и сделать над ними операции
  }`

Comment: в общем короткий ответ - с Number это не будет работать, можно метод перегрузить для нужных типов данных

Comment: фактически то, что я описал как раз таки ранее http://stackoverflow.com/a/29011456/6104996

Comment: @AdamSkywalke задача в том, что бы метод принимал любые числовые типы и возвращал ответ такого же типа как и аргумент

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `-` в *Java* применяется только к примитивным числовым типам или их боксовым версиям:

> ... the type of each of the operands of the binary - operator must be a
>   type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Тип `Number` не относится к конвертируемым в примитивные числовые типу.

Возможное решение - добавить проверку типа аргументов, перебрав всех потомков `Number`, и обработку для каждого типа, фактически продублировав код, который написан сейчас, для каждого случая.

Comment: не проще ли в таком случае использовать классы - обертки и проводить операции с ними?

Comment: @KVV в Java **нет** перегрузки операторов. **Совсем**.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
private static <T extends Number> T middler(T arg1, T arg2){
    T res = (arg2.doubleValue() +(arg1.doubleValue()-arg2.doubleValue())/2);
    return res.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: В данном случае компилятор не позволит резyльтат выражения типа Double присвоить переменной типа T

Comment: Тогда можно сделать так:
return (arg2.doubleValue() +(arg1.doubleValue()-arg2.doubleValue())/2);

Comment: А так он поругается что ты попросил метод возвращать тип Т, а сам пытаешься пропихнуть Double

Answer (score 0):

Влезу я со своими 5-ю копейками.

Как я писал ранее, можно сделать проверку на принадлежность к классу. И в зависимости от этого приводить аргументы к типу и вычислять.

```
public static < T extends Number > T middler(T arg1, T arg2) {

  if (arg1 == null || arg2 == null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (arg1 instanceof Double) {
    return (T) new Double((arg1.doubleValue() + (arg2.doubleValue() - arg1.doubleValue())) / 2);
  } else if (arg1 instanceof Integer) {
    return (T) new Integer((arg1.intValue() + (arg2.intValue() - arg1.intValue())) / 2);
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type " + arg1.getClass() + " is not supported by this method");
  }
}
```

Но выглядит это конечно не очень красиво и, скорее, лучше для разных типов, в данном случае, сделать просто перегруженный метод принимающий свои типы входных аргументов